# Не могу загрузить фото телеграм-ботом на сервис ImgBB

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, requests

Бота делаю с помощью библиотеки aiogram.  Основная задача от бота - это получить фото от пользователя и загрузить его на сервис (желательно в выбранный альбом на сервисе). Этот сервис (imgbb) предоставляет API-токен и по идее все должно работать

ссылка сайта
https://imgbb.com

```
ALBUM_ID = 'Hf3CPd'
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'send_photo', state= UserState)
async def send_photo(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(user_id, "Скиньте фотографию")

    await UserState.photo_process.set()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO, state= UserState.photo_process)
async def handle_photo(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    photo_file = await message.photo[-1]

    url = "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload"
    data = {
        "key": STORAGE_API_KEY,
        "image": photo_file,
        "album": ALBUM_ID,
    }
    requests.post(url, data)

    await bot.send_message(user_id, "Вы загрузили фотографию")
```

Чтобы получить айди альбома, я создал альбом и зашел в него, а айди взял с адресной строки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется я многое упускаю либо это нереально реализовать

Comment: не очень понятно из описания, на каком этапе проблема. как это связать с приведённым кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможные пути к решению вашей проблемы:

1. Заходим в документацию api imgbb (https://api.imgbb.com)

   Проходимся по пунктам и видим, что параметр image должен быть в
   формате бинарного файла, кодировке base64 или ссылкой URL на
   изображение.

   Самый простой вариант - кодировка base64.

   Как пример:

   ```python
   import base64

   with open("file.png", "rb") as image_file:
       encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
   ```

Открываем изображение с помощью open и кодируем его в необходимый
формат. После данных манипуляций можем отправлять параметр image.

2. Что касается альбома, такого параметра в api нет, в данном вопросе помогут только эксперименты при загрузке.
3. Использование библиотеки.

   Не зачем заново изобретать велосипед, попробуйте использовать уже
   созданный.

   Библиотека imgbbpy (https://pypi.org/project/imgbbpy) может помочь в
   вашем вопросе. Есть все необходимые функции и параметры для загрузки
   (альбом отсутствует, но можно попробовать расширить функционал)

Если останутся вопросы или не сможете найти метод как загрузить фото
в альбом, можете написать в комментариях, возможно подскажу по
решению данной проблемы.